# Can Antlr route embedded grammars to a seperate file for processing?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, antlr4

We are processing some fairly large java files. Embedded in the java are a variety of non java statements/files (SQL being the most prevalent). I could extend the grammar but for our purposes, it would be a lot more efficient to send the errant statements on another channel, collect those and parse. Or find some way to isolate those. We currently do this for comments as the comments contain additional information that is necessary.

Any suggestions on how to deal with embedded island grammars elegantly ?

This is an example where we need to parse the database call as well as the language

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con) throws SQLException {

    String query = "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, " +
                   "SALES, TOTAL " +
                   "from COFFEES";

    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
            int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
            float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
            int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
            int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");
            System.out.println(coffeeName + ", " + supplierID +
                               ", " + price + ", " + sales +
                               ", " + total);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    }
}
```

the code processes correctly (it is valid Java) but we need to pull the SQL statements out and run them through a post process.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing examples of these embedded statements. If the grammar doesn't recognise it, it usually cannot recover from it properly, making it not very logical to just go ahead and continue parsing.

Comment: I went ahead and put an example up although you are probably going to think its too basic. The issue is that I have to parse the SQL, not just a string. The DDL has been parsed already, and I need to connect the symbol table from the DDL to the symbol table in the Java. So we parse each language seperately. I suspect the same situation will start to occur as we move up into HTML as well.

Comment: But that's not non java statements/files. That's a valid Java string representing an SQL statement. I don't understand what you are doing exactly. You mean to say that parsing the Java snippet from your question goes wrong?

Comment: I rephrased it again as you are correct, its not an error. The string query contains a 'select COF_NAME' (col name obviously) which may or may not exist in the db. I'm working the process from the database back to the program. I have the DDL parsed, so the field COF_NAME is likely in the symbol table for that parse. I'm looking for a more elegant way, besides analyzing every stmt.executeQuery(query) to push those into a separate analysis process. Think GDPR - you need to be able to follow a social security number from DB to UI through the transformations. Thats close to what we are doing here.

Comment: This happens also with Antlr action blocks, which I've been wanting to parse for an Antlr LSP server. In this and in your case, because you can assume the boundary for the embedded language is within a lexical token of the "super" language, maybe you could create and call a parse of the int stream for the embedded language, using a custom token to embed this parse tree in the token of the super language? When you go to evaluate the static semantics on the entire tree, you could then check whether "COF_NAME" exists in the SQL. But, it sounds like you do something like this already.

Comment: Clever. Yeah, an intermediate string type might do it. I'll look into both alternatives. Thinking about your response, maybe I attack it backwards. I can always get the string objects from the symbol table, write the ones with desired keywords to a file (.sql) then lex/parse the sql separately. Maybe read the sql grammar and pull keywords. Won't be 100% but it will be a lot closer. Good suggestion.

Comment: I'm trying this for Antlr with embedded C# for the entire action block and the parsing works great, leaving off the stream at the right place! Thanks for asking this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a way to accomplish this, just not the way I had intended. Kaby76 was spot on, we ended up post parsing the strings looking for certain verbs which we had already implemented, loading the post process strings into a file and then running antlr against those files. It isn't "elegant" but it does work (which is all I can ask for)